# How can i get aframe box vertex coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I need to get vertex from an object (box) in an AFRAME or i need to calculate intersection between raycaster and the face of an  entity.
Someone can help me? Thank you all!ç

EDIT: I added code below.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("intersection-handler", {
  schema: {
    fps: { type: 'number', default: 15 }
  },

  init: function() {
    this.bindMethods();

  },

  tick: function(){

    if(new Date().getTime()-this.lastTick<(1000/this.data.fps))return;
    if(this.isIntersecting){
      let distance = this.calculateDistance(this.el.object3D.position, this.hittedElem.object3D.position);
      this.el.emit('intersection-detected-' + this.el.id, distance );
    }else{
      this.el.emit('intersection-cleared-' + this.el.id);
    }
    this.lastTick = new Date().getTime();
  },

  bindMethods(){ // You could do all of this directly in your init() method, but I like to separate it.
    this.onIntersection = this.onIntersection.bind(this);
    this.onIntersectionClear = this.onIntersectionClear.bind(this);
  },

  play: function() {
    this.registerEventListeners();  // It's a good practice in general to enable your event listeners here.
  },

  pause: function() {
    this.deregisterEventListeners(); // Similarly a good practice to remove them here so that they don't stay bound while the scene isn't actually 'running'
  },

  registerEventListeners() {

    this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', this.onIntersection);
    this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection-cleared', this.onIntersectionClear);
  },

  deregisterEventListeners() {

    this.el.removeEventListener('raycaster-intersection', this.onIntersection);
    this.el.removeEventListener('raycaster-intersection-cleared', this.onIntersectionClear);
  },

  onIntersection: function(e) {
    console.log(this.el.components.raycaster.getIntersection(e.detail.els[0]))


    this.isIntersecting = true;
    if(e.detail.intersections[0].object){
      this.hittedElem = e.detail.intersections[0].object.el;
    }
  },

  onIntersectionClear: function(e) {

    this.isIntersecting = false;
  },

  calculateDistance: function(myElposition, hittedElposition) {
    // distance = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2) - rolloff
    let rolloffFactor = 0.5;
    let d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((hittedElposition.x - myElposition.x), 2) + Math.pow((hittedElposition.y - myElposition.y), 2)) - rolloffFactor;
    return d;
  }

});
```

I can't use the raycaster-intersected event, i'm managing intersections on raycaster side not in the other entities.

Comment: Without more detail it is unclear what you are asking. Please clarify what you mean and include any example code showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have a robot with a raycaster and i want to detect the intersection point every tick() but raycaster-intersection only fires once on every new intersection but if the intersection is still ocurring it doesn't fires any more and i can't get the distance yo the intersection point. As soon as i can i will copy some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for the vertex coordinates. The raycasters intersection.point contains a `Vector3` with the intersection position.

On the other hand if you get your camera (raycasters origin) position, you get another `Vector3`.

From the [three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3), you can get the distance between them with a simple `a.distanceTo(b)`.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/sa4d8237/16/).

Comment: Yes i know It returns the distance but just on new interesections, i'm asking ti get distance on the same intersection on every tick() . What i say is, raycaster-intersection only fires once noticias on every tick, cause if that i cant get the distance on every tick().

Comment: did you check the console in my fiddle ? should output the distance on each tick

Comment: I just see it! I will give it a try and adapt to my code.

Comment: Okey, i see my problem i was using AFRAME v0.8.0 and the function "getIntersection()" is available on newer versions. The problem seems fixed. Thank you so much!!! :)